# Vuetify - display a header and a v-card together with full size vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div style="height: 20px; color: yellow">
      test
    </div>
    <v-card class="markdown-preview" tile>
      <v-card-text v-html="previewText"> </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>
```

The v-card should take the remaining place in the div, no matter which size the header div has.
I tried it with flex, but the v-card is either directly on top or the its overflowing the parent div at the bottom.
Can someone please help me? I tried so much different options for hours. My only solution was with calculated css properties. But I want the values to be variable.

Comment: Try using `height: 100%` on the `v-card`

Comment: then its overflowing the bottom. I it 100% of the div, but I only have place of (100% - size of header div).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display flex for this.
Define the parent as `display: flex` and then define the v-card as `flex: 1`.

```
<template>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <div style="height: 20px; color: yellow">
            test
        </div>
        <v-card class="markdown-preview" style="flex: 1;" tile>
            <v-card-text v-html="previewText"> </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks it works! But I have one more question. I have a footer with flexible height, too.
I use v-footer-bar for that. But the content is ignoring the footer.
If I wrap the footer in a div and give it a height everything works. But I don't know the height every time.

Comment: You can use `height: auto`, and the footer will adjust automatically as per the content.

Comment: yeah I tried that but height auto gives the footer a height of 0 and the content is directly at the bottom.
If I use the footer directly without a wrapper div, the footer hat the right size, but the content is also directly at the bottom.

Comment: ah i made it, it was because of the absolute attribute of the footer..